# How to load scroll view of some place directly

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

I have added a scroll view of content size 320,1000 to my view. It's working properly and loading with starting content of scroll view. But, now I want it like showing some place of it when its getting load. That is it shows directly some place of it instead of starting of the content

I have tried with

```
[scrollView1 scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(60, 300, 240, 40) animated:NO];
[scrollView1 zoomToRect:CGRectMake(60, 300, 240, 40) animated:YES];
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake( 0 , 300 )];
```

Use after setting the content size.